# Match On Multiple Rows Without Multiple Joins, Aggregates, or Sub Selects?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Products and Features. Products has a one-to-many join to products.

I would like to find all products that have both features "blue" and "green".

The only ways I know how to do this is through mutliple joins or aggregates.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE features (
  product_id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO products (id) VALUES 
(1);

INSERT INTO features (product_id, name) VALUES 
(1, "blue"),
(1, "green");
```

Attempts:

```
-- Desired solution
SELECT p.id FROM products p
  JOIN features f ON f.product_id = p.id
  WHERE f.name = 'blue' AND f.name = 'green';

-- Solution 1: Multiple joines
SELECT p.id FROM products p
  JOIN features f1 ON f1.product_id = p.id
  JOIN features f2 ON f2.product_id = p.id
  WHERE f1.name = 'blue' AND f2.name = 'green';

-- Solution 2: Aggregates
SELECT x.id, MAX(x.cnd_1) AS cnd_1, MAX(x.cnd_2) AS cnd_2 FROM (
  SELECT p.id, 
    CASE WHEN f.name = 'blue' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS cnd_1,
    CASE WHEN f.name = 'green' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS cnd_2
  FROM products p
  JOIN features f ON f.product_id = p.id
) x GROUP BY 1
HAVING(cnd_1 = TRUE and cnd_2 = TRUE);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b03925/37)

While I do technically have 2 working solutions. The first solution doesn't scale well and the second solution is a mess. I'm generating queries with dozens of these conditions.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Products has a one-to-many join to products.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM products p
JOIN features f ON f.product_id = p.id
WHERE f.name IN ('blue', 'green')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.name) = 2;
```